# Configuring Spring MockMvc to use custom argument resolver before built-in ones

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a straightforward test case. I have a controller which has a parameter of a type Spring doesn't support by default, so I wrote a custom resolver.

I create the mock mvc instance I'm using like so:

```
mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setCustomArgumentResolvers(new GoogleOAuthUserResolver()).build();
```

However, Spring is also registering almost 30 other argument resolvers, one of which is general enough that it is getting used to resolve the argument before mine. How can I set or sort the resolvers so that mine is invoked first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the `People` class the Google OAuth library I am using extends `Map` and the mock servlet API provides no way to manipulate the order in which the handlers are registered.

I ended up using reflection to reach into the mocks guts and remove the offending handler.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me without reflection:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class CustomerNumberArgumentResolverRegistration {

  private final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

  @PostConstruct
  public void prioritizeCustomArgumentResolver () {
    final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<>(Objects.requireNonNull(requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getArgumentResolvers()));
    argumentResolvers.add(0, new CustomerNumberArgumentResolver());
    requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
  }

}
```